# Failing trying to build npm

Tags: npm, build

I am getting this error after running `npm run build`:

```
15 silly lifecycle myproject@1.0.0~build: Args: [
15 silly lifecycle   '-c',
15 silly lifecycle   'node ./update-build.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout'
15 silly lifecycle ]
16 silly lifecycle myproject@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
17 info lifecycle myproject@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
18 verbose stack Error: myproject@1.0.0 build: `node ./update-build.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout`
18 verbose stack Exit status 2
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
19 verbose pkgid myprojectb@1.0.0
20 verbose cwd /home/user/myproject
21 verbose Linux 5.4.0-83-generic
22 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
```

My nodejs version is 12.22.1 and npm version is 6.14.12, also I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Any hint on how to deal with it?

Comment: What happens if we take `npm` out of it? Does running `node ./update-build.js` succeed? If so, how about `npx cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout`?

Comment: @Trott it is working, thanks